# How do I determine what IP range to use given how many hosts and networks I want?

Tags: ip, subnet

I need to figure out this question, but I do not know how to go about it. I am new to subnetting, and this is a question on my Microsoft Networking Security Fundamentals assessment:

The IT director has asked you to set up 14 separate IP networks
that can each have up to 400 computers. What IANA private IP range should you
select?

a. 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255

b. 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255

c. 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255

d. 169.254.0.0-169.254.255.255

The answer, I have been told, is B. But why? Couldn't both B and D fulfill the request?

Comment: What are the private address ranges? Check _[RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918)_.

Comment: If your question would be closed, https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com may be a better match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the D is the only option that you can't use, because `169.254.0.0/16` is [reserved](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) for *Link Local* instead of *Private-Use* like all the others. However, it's possible to have these 14 networks of up to 400 computers to fit in any of the `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`:

- The `10.0.0.0/8` is the widest of these with 16,777,216 addresses, so it'll easily do this. The difference between `10.0.0.0/8` and `172.16.0.0/12` (1,048,576 IPs) in this manner is so little compared to the amount of 14x400 = 5600 devices that it doesn't need further discussion.
- The `192.168.0.0/16` is probably considered as a "wrong answer", because the 400 doesn't fit into one `/24` of 256 hosts. However, with *Classless Inter-Domain Routing* (CIDR) you don't need to stick to the limitations of *classful networks*, where `172.16.0.0/12` would have been the only suitable solution.

  - You could arrange the network for example as 14 x `/23` subnets, with 512 hosts each:

    - `192.168.100.0/23`; from `192.168.100.0` to `192.168.101.255`
    - `192.168.102.0/23`; from `192.168.102.0` to `192.168.103.255`
    - `192.168.104.0/23`; from `192.168.104.0` to `192.168.105.255`
    - ...
    - `192.168.126.0/23`; from `192.168.126.0` to `192.168.127.255`
  - ..as well as 14 x `/22` subnets, with 1024 hosts each, etc. etc.

    - `192.168.100.0/22`; from `192.168.100.0` to `192.168.103.255`
    - `192.168.104.0/22`; from `192.168.104.0` to `192.168.107.255`
    - `192.168.108.0/22`; from `192.168.108.0` to `192.168.111.255`
    - ...
    - `192.168.152.0/22`; from `192.168.152.0` to `192.168.155.255`